# PHP access level system using session array

Tags: php

I have a login and register system that is working fine, although I want to add user access levels so that users with admin access can go on a page that regular users can't. I have my code echoing just so I know if it is actually work at the moment.

This is the code I'm using:

```
echo("Hello $_SESSION[user]"); 

if ($_SESSION['user']==1) {
    echo "You have admin access";
} else {
    echo "You're a regular user";
}
```

So basically, if a user have a level 1 in the database, they are an admin and anyone below that is a regular user.

The problem is it never works, it always displays "You're a regular user"

And my code:

```
echo("Hello $_SESSION[user]");
```

echo's out this "Hello ArrayYou're a regular user"

I know my login system has the session set for user, but it says it is an array.

Here is my login page, I didn't make it since I'm new to PHP: http://pastebin.com/h0zqnNSe

And for anyone that is curious, I know the level row in my database is working because I have echoed that out fine using another script, as you can see [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tg2uH.png)

Comment: can yo do a `print_r($_SESSION)`?  if my guess is correct... Can you try `echo("Hello {$_SESSION['user']}"); `

Comment: @roullie Yes it showed all of my information correctly from the database like: You're a regular userArray ( [user] => Array ( [id] => 1 [username] => FireX [email] => email@gmail.com) )

Comment: Note that my answer was updated -- I had the wrong line at first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SESSION['user']` is an associative array, containing various attributes of the user retrieved from the database. The ID number is in the `id` element of this array, so you need to do:

```
echo("Hello {$_SESSION['user']['username']} (ID = {$_SESSION['user']['id']})"); 

if ($_SESSION['user']['id']==1) {
    echo "You have admin access";
} else {
    echo "You're a regular user";
}
```

Comment: This is probably the best answers so far, but I changed my access level in the database and it is just staying at "You have admin access" http://puu.sh/mDC7s/d32ad7c8da.png

Comment: This code is checking the ID, not the access level.

Answer (score 0):

At the top of the page you need to add

```
session_start();
```

See here for all the info:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php

As @Barmar answer show this was the other missing piece $_SESSION['user']['id']

Comment: Hmm... I added it and got the same results

Comment: You will need that bit of code for this to work. $_SESSION['user'] looks to be a row from the DB. Can you echo out that and provide that detail. Either the row or the session.